How to decide which spline to use when conducting g-computation after weighting?
I've conducted statistical weighting (R package WeightIt) and I am now using g-computation (R package marginal effects) to estimate the effect of % tree cover on crop yield (following https://ngreifer.github.io/WeightIt/articles/estimating-effects.html). I don't expect the relationship to be linear, so I would like to use a natural spline, but I am unsure how many df to specify and, for example, df=4 and df=2 result in very different outcomes & interpretations. Conducting model selection (eg using AIC) doesn't quite feel appropriate as it is a predictive technique and not appropriate for causal inference. So how do I pick the right number of df for my spline?

I don't think there is a good way to to determine the degrees of freedom.  It depends on how "wiggly" you think the conditional mean is.  Generally, more df means more willingness, but if you have lots of data then that isn't such a big deal.
My advice would be to use 3-5 knots in your spline, perhaps placed according to the rules Frank Harrell describes in Chapter 2 of his book Regression Modelling Strategies.  Then, you can do some sensitivity analysis to determine how the degrees of freedom change the results.  They should not change appreciably due to number of knots.
The other option you have is to use a generalized additive model, which has some techniques for choosing the "optimal wiggliness".

(+1) Nice answer, that's basically what I say in the guide but I'm still learning about splines so didn't have a good justification for it. Unfortunately GAMs aren't very compatible with weighting and inference on GAMs (which is designed to account for regularizing the wiggliness) is not obviously compatible with inference for weighting, which is why I recommended splines first. Local linear regression is another option but still requires bandwidth selection.

@Noah Thanks.  Would you mind explaining what you mean when you say that GAM's are not obviously compatible with inference for weighting?

@DemetriPananos Crudely, you have a weight per observation so you know what to do with sums over observations, but the smoothing penalty is not a sum over observations and it's not at all obvious how the weights should go into it.  This is ok for curve fitting but much more of a problem for inference.

Maybe I'm missing something, but you could do bootstrap inference after weighting a GAM, right? And the smoothing parameters could be selected before weighting to have a "best-fitting" outcome model that is weighted in a next step, which is kind of how model selection is usually handled for doubly robust estimators. Unpenalized natural cubic splines are great of course (and the OP is well-served by @DemetriPananos answer), but I love penalized splines for issues like this.
